# nodeJS: convert response.body in utf-8 (from windows-1251 encoding)

Tags: node.js, encoding

I'm trying to convert an HTML body encoded in `windows-1251` into `utf-8` but I still get messed up characters on `html`.

They are basically Russian alphabet but I can't get them to be shown properly. I get `??????? ?? ???`

```
const GOT = require('got') // https://www.npmjs.com/package/got
const WIN1251 = require('windows-1251') // https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1251

async function query() {
    var body = Buffer.from(await GOT('https://example.net/', {resolveBodyOnly: true}), 'binary')
    var html = WIN1251.decode(body.toString('utf8'))
    console.log(html)
}

query()
```

[image]

Comment: `body.toString('utf8')` is probably wrong, because if `body` isn't UTF-8, this step would already replace invalid CP1251 characters.

Comment: @Evert I also tried `body.toString()`

Comment: Don't do that either. Strings in javascript _are_ in unicode, so if you convert it to a string before converting it from CP1251 it's always going to be wrong. Does your CP1251 library let you use buffers as input?

Comment: I gues it will accept text only: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1251

Comment: Is your nodejs server running on windows ? I struggled also with converting encodings.., what i've done is to use a powershell script which encoded it always to utf-8 without need to specify input format. The script was called from the nodejs app via child_process and contained basically only this line: `$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding($False)` + reading and writing the file ofc..

Comment: Hello. Can I get some example of HTML encoded in windows-1251? or the URL?

Comment: For **an example**, see `<meta charset="Windows-1251">` in https://rutracker.org/ html source

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’re doing a lot of silly encoding back-and-forth here.  And the ‘backs’ don’t even match the ‘forths’.

First, you use the `got` library to download a webpage; by default, [`got` will dutifully decode response texts as UTF-8](https://github.com/sindresorhus/got/tree/c0b5346433996e761bca15cdb942f2b740264118#encoding).  You [stuff the returned Unicode string into a `Buffer` with the `binary` encoding](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding), which throws away the higher octet of each UTF-16 code unit of the Unicode string.  Then you use [`.toString('utf-8')`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end) which interprets this mutilated string as UTF-8 (in actuality, it is most likely not valid UTF-8 at all).  Then you pass the ‘UTF-8’ string to the `windows-1251`, to decode it as a ‘code page 1251’ string.  Nothing good can possibly come from all this confusion.

The `windows-1251` package you want to use takes so-called ‘binary’ (pseudo-Latin-1) strings as input.  What you should do instead is take the binary response, interpret it as [Latin-1/‘binary’ string](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) and then pass it to the `windows-1251` library for decoding.

In other words, use this:

```
const GOT = require('got');
const WIN1251 = require('windows-1251');

async function query() {
    const body = await GOT('https://example.net/', {
        resolveBodyOnly: true,
        responseType: 'buffer'
    });
    const html = WIN1251.decode(body.toString('binary'))
    console.log(html)
}

query()
```

Comment: can we  help the poor guy without calling his try silly? :D

Comment: Programming by permutation is always worth calling out, I think.